# center two columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center two columns that are inside one container:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but I'm getting all my divs at the left side. I know that both columns are taken 8 columns, So I'm missing 4 of them, But how can I ignore those 4 columns and just center my container? I know how to do this with simple css but I supose bootstrap handle this in a better way to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `Offsetting columns` here is the [reference link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Read it and DIY.

example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <p>Here Comes Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p>Here Comes Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Since you have 4 columns extra, you need to move 2 columns from the left (**col-md-offset-2**).

Answer (score 3):

If using bootstrap 4, you can use `.row .justify-content-md-center`  for columns align center.

```
<div class='row justify-content-md-center'>

 <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12'>
  Some text here...
 </div>

 <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12'>
  Some text here...
 </div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying the flex on **row class** works for me

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```